# Replace text in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following:

```
<li class="product_promo promo_code_227598" id="discount_14902941">
    <img src="/wcsstore/ConsumerDirectStorefrontAssetStore/images/discount.gif" alt="" align="middle">
    -2-for-10-
</li>
```

I want to replace the first and last character of the text only.

I have tried the following but it replaces the contents of the element:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^-+|-+$/g,''));
```

I have also tried the following but the first dash does not get replaced.

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/^-+|-+$/g,''));
```

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking

Comment: Expected output:  `code` <li class="product_promo promo_code_227598" id="discount_14902941">
    <img src="/wcsstore/ConsumerDirectStorefrontAssetStore/images/discount.gif" alt="" align="middle">2-for-10
</li>

Comment: I note on your comment to a delete answer that you're using jQuery 1.3.2.   _Please, please_ consider upgrading!

Comment: @C-link please undelete your answer - it's the right way of doing it with any sane version of jQuery...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade it just yet as it is a corporate site rather than personal. Is there a way to this at the moment?

Comment: @Alnitak I've undeleted my answer, but I don't think the answer is the way for the OP.

Comment: @C-link suggest you put a note in your answer declaring the version of jQuery that added that funcitonality

Answer (score 1):

```
var len = $.trim($("li").text());

var res = len.slice(1,len.length-1);

$("li").contents().last()[0].textContent = res; // this way you can append the text without affcet the html tag
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HbbLA/)

Comment: This work but I just need to replace the text if I now do: $(this).text(len.slice(1,len.length-1)); It replaces the image.

Comment: Thanks for this works perfectly on newer version of jquery but not 1.3.2 which I cannot upgrade at the moment.

Comment: I have worked it out:   `var len = $.trim($(this).text());
   var res = len.slice(1,len.length-1);
   $(this).contents()[2].data = res;`

Comment: oh it is a better way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).text(function(i, v){
  return v.replace(/^-+|-+$/g,'');
});
```

Please note: This works only on jQuery version 1.4 and further.

Comment: This just outputs (probably should have said using a very old version of jquery 1.3.2) - FUNCTION (I, V){
 RETURN V.REPLACE(/^-+|-+$/G,'');
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/^[-+]|[-+]$/g,''));
```

Comment: Doesn't replace the first dash only the last

Comment: @user2025749 Not true: `"-asdasd-".replace(/^[-+]|[-+]$/g,"")` gives `"asdasd"`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @OlivierH This solves the question for replacing leading and trailing dash in a text.